# Computing recurrence relation with direct iteration

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations

I have this recurrence relation, and I am trying to compute $E_n$ using the direct iteration method.

$E_k = E_{k-1} + \frac{k+1}{2}$ for each integer $k \geq 2$.
$E_1 = 0$

I plugged in a few values for k, and got

$E_n = \frac{n+1}{2} + \frac{n}{2} + \frac{n-1}{2}+...+\frac{3}{2}+0$

but I'm not really sure where to go from there to turn it into a better computation of $E_n$, which I can then verify with induction.

Comment: Are you sure the recurrence relation is correct? It seems to me that $E_1 = E_2 + 1$ so $E_2 = -1$ and the rest of the sequence is negative. Also, don’t forget the standard formula for the sum of integers: 1 + 2 + … + k = k(k+1)/2.

Comment: Oops, you're right! It is supposed to be $E_{k-1}$, not +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simplify $E_n$:
$$E_n = \frac{n+1}{2} + \frac{n}{2} + \frac{n-1}{2}+\dots+\frac{3}{2}+0$$
$$E_n = \frac{(n+1) + n + (n-1) + \dots + 3}{2}$$
Let's make the numerator into a sum we know what to do with:
$$E_n = \frac{(n+1) + n + (n-1) + \dots +3+2+1}{2} - \frac{3}{2}$$
$$E_n = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}i}{2} - \frac{3}{2}$$
$$E_n = \frac{\frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{2}}{2} - \frac{3}{2}$$
And the final result:
$$E_n = \frac{(n+2)(n+1) - 6}{4}$$
A quick check comparing the given method of computing $E_n$ with its simplification for $n = 4$ verifies the method.
$$E_4 = \frac{(4+2)(4+1) - 6}{4} = \frac{30 - 6}{4} = 6$$
$$E_4 = \frac{5}{2} + \frac{4}{2} + \frac{3}{2} = \frac{12}{2} = 6$$